# equivalent to `kubectl delete pods --all -n namespace` in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I need to simply recreate all the pods on certain releases, say 10 in number, on a production cluster.
Is there a `helm` command to loop over release names and pods under each release should be deleted and then recreated. any hints?

I am familiar with

```sh
for nmspc in $namespace_list; do kubectl delete pods -n $nmspc; done
```

However, I am trying to see if there is an equivalent helm command to do the same, such that once pods are deleted under the releases, they are spun up again.

```sh
for rlsz in $release_list; do helm delete pods -n $rlsz; done
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

@Alex Pakka suggested you right approach with `helm upgrade --recreate-pods <release_name> path/to/chart`, but yeah  sometimes it depends on chart.

Just for example I took `nginx-ingress-1.15.0.tgz` from `stable/nginx-ingress`

```
helm fetch stable/nginx-ingress
```

and installed in standard way

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system nginx-ingress-1.15.0.tgz
```

After deploying I was able successfully recreate pods with the below command:

`helm upgrade --recreate-pods nginx-ingress nginx-ingress-1.15.0.tgz --username "xxxxx" --password "xxxxx"`

```
---
nginx-ingress-controller-cd996946d-95ndx                       1/1     Running   0          47s
nginx-ingress-default-backend-77c7c664bb-2nsdp                 1/1     Running   0          46s
---
nginx-ingress-controller-cd996946d-95ndx                       1/1     Terminating         0          93s
nginx-ingress-controller-cd996946d-dd6dc                       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
nginx-ingress-default-backend-77c7c664bb-2nsdp                 1/1     Terminating         0          92s
nginx-ingress-default-backend-77c7c664bb-mnrvj                 0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
---
nginx-ingress-controller-cd996946d-dd6dc                       1/1     Running   0          21s
nginx-ingress-default-backend-77c7c664bb-mnrvj                 1/1     Running   0          21s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
helm upgrade --recreate-pods <release_name> path/to/chart
```

If your charts are organized in a list of directories, and directory name corresponds to release name (recommended approach), you can use

```
for d in */ ; do
    helm upgrade --recreate-pods "${d%?} "${d}"
done
```

where `${d%?}` removes trailing slash from directory name.

Note, that by definition, recreate-pods will cause downtime.

If you simply want to restart the pods, and they are all deployed via Helm, you can simply do

```
kubectl delete pods -n my-namespace --all
```

Tiller will re-create them, as if they crashed.

Comment: `helm upgrade` needs 2 params: release name and path to the chart. Not all the information from charts is stored inside Kubernetes and is not available to Tiller. However, I updated my answer with another method that might suit you better.

Comment: thanks: I am familiar with kubectl delete but just wanted to use helm delete as a standard procedure coz releases are deployed via helm so we want to do any related operation also via the same. hence the call.

Comment: am getting 400 error.. 

helm upgrade --recreate-pods namespace-manager https://aws-sw-file.tgz --username "xxxxx" --password "xxxxx" --dry-run --debug

Comment: @AhmFM it is hard to say what caused 400 Bad Request - could be ssl/certificate issue, could be version incompatibility, could be the content of tgz file does not start with Chart.yaml having `name: namespace-manager`...